# Enable Flash Plugin in qml Webview

Tags: qml

How to Enable Flash Plugin in qml Webview?

I've tried:

```
WebView {
    width: 200; height: 200
    settings.pluginsEnabled: true
    html:"<html><head></head><body><object width="425" height="350" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/........." type="application/x-shockwave-flash"><param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/........."></object></body></html>"
}
```

It works well on the pc using Chrome for ex, but on a symbian device (E7) it shows only a plugin icon